# Module to display blank theme template

Tags: 7, routes

I am creating a module with a map displaying markers. Do I need to create a page/ node or can I load the drupal theme without any page / node content and add my code.

```
<?php /**
 * Implementation of hook_menu.
 */
function projects_map_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['projects-on-map'] = array(
    'title' => 'Projects on Map',
    'page callback' => 'projects_map_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access argument' => array('access nodes'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback
 */
function projects_map_page() {
//render them current theme
//custom code
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the map or just build the map? If you want to show the map you can just return anything you want in the projects_map_page() and it will show up at http://www.example.com/projects-on-map

Comment: yes, but if I put echo 'asdfdsfdf'; it just returns that text with no theme

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.org/node/1238606 and http://11heavens.com/theming-Drupal-6-from-the-module-layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create this functionality using the [Geolocation Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation_views) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is sub-module for [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation) to display markers on Google Map using Views 3.
>
> Module support:
>
> - show content in Info Windows
> - custom marker images
> - markers as links
> - multiple maps on a single page
> - support MarkerClusterer